# Where do Kubernetes components log output?

Tags: kubernetes, glog

Attempting to Debug why AzureDisk won't always mount. Logs for the pod show a timeout, but Kubernetes pkg components have glog calls. Where do these get logged to and how can I see them?

Example:
 [azure_managedDiskController.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/azure/azure_managedDiskController.go)

```
if err != nil {
    glog.V(2).Infof("azureDisk - created new MD Name:%s StorageAccountType:%s Size:%v but was unable to confirm provisioningState in poll process", diskName, storageAccountType, sizeGB)
} else {
    glog.V(2).Infof("azureDisk - created new MD Name:%s StorageAccountType:%s Size:%v", diskName, storageAccountType, sizeGB)
}
```

Comment: k8s components are just processes running on the nodes. The common case is for them to be lifecycle-managed by systemd, and log to journald. If you can get onto the nodes on which your pods are running, try using journalctl.

Comment: @JonahBenton wouldn't it be helpful if we could get at those logs without logging into those machines. :/

Comment: :) agree though that's not a problem that's unique to k8s. Common case is to set up some sort of log aggregation for the cluster, like on-prem ELK or some third party service like Sumo, apart from any application-tier log mgmt integration.